# Consume API with basic authentication using Javascript without exposing key pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript

I have a private API, where I'm using basic authentication as my security layer. Right now the API is consumed by my iOS app, so no one is able to see the key pair.

I'm creating the same app for the web now, using React and Javascript and need to consume the same API using basic authentication.

How can I use my API key pair in Javascript without exposing that key pair to the public? Is such a thing even possible?

Comment: you give each user their own or put something in between them and the API like a reverse proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew mentioned, that is not possible, you can just make it harder to get, but it'll be there somewhere on the client code, and that's enough to say you're exposing it.

If you're open to alternatives, I suggest you to use a per user authentication for the first request, and then a token based authentication for further requests. That token can be a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/introduction/) and it's the flow I'm talking about:

[image: diagram]

This is the way it works, taken from [JWT's official documentation](https://jwt.io/introduction/):

> **In authentication, when the user successfully logs in using their
>   credentials, a JSON Web Token will be returned and must be saved
>   locally** (typically in local storage, but cookies can be also used),
>   instead of the traditional approach of creating a session in the
>   server and returning a cookie.
>
> **Whenever the user wants to access a protected route or resource, the
>   user agent should send the JWT, typically in the Authorization header
>   using the Bearer schema**. The content of the header should look like
>   the following:
>
> ```
> Authorization: Bearer <token>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer and example of what I could do. I'm using Firebase for my user authentication and was wondering if I could use OAuth to authenticate with my API. I've set up another question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881568/securing-restful-api-with-firebase-oauth - if have the time to point me further in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: No.

If the client needs to be able to connect to the API directly, there is no surefire way to prevent them from discovering the API key, as they must, by design, be able to access it in order to send it in the request. You can take measures to obfuscate it, by storing it encoded (but the client will have to have the decoding algorithm as well).

This is in fact also true with your iOS app. Someone can reverse engineer the binary or intercept the requests and view the header, discovering the API key.

A possible “solution” is likely to have each client get their own API key, be it temporary or permanent, that is in someway locked to their account/device/session to limit reuse.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I'm using Firebase for my user authentication and was wondering if I could use OAuth to authenticate with my API. I've set up another question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881568/securing-restful-api-with-firebase-oauth - if have the time to point me further in the right direction.